# Restricting sessions to only 1 instance of a user login

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

i have a user login system which works off of sessions such that when the user logs in a session variable of user is populated with his/her username, then each page she loads checks this session, if it is not populated then the page is redirected to the login page. apon logout the session is destroyed.

But this still allows a user to open 2 different browsers at the same time and login. I want to stop this, such that if a user logs in and then trys to login using a different browser or pc, they get an error saying the user is already logged in.

So my first thought was to use a data base write, but then how do i know to unset that value if the browser is closed?

all my pages are php, and i use ajax and php scripts to update dynamic content.

So whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they get an error saying the user is already logged in.

That's wrong approach, causing terrible user's experience.

Make it opposite: let that latter in, but make previous one logged out. 
You only need to store current session ID in the user's table. If it doesn't match - ask for login.

Answer (score 1):

If you find in DB that user is already logged in simply ask if he/she wants to go on and overwrite old session info. Another way may be adding a time-ticket to your database information (e.g. inserting time) and check how long is elapsed since inserted.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, I think you can make use of cookie. Once user is logged in, you can create a cookie and set an expiry to browser session time. Before fetching data from DB, you need to check for cookie presence.

Answer (score 0):

I would make another session variable that checks the browser type, if it is different call a view method to output what you said